# Link 2 fields together and make them unique when combined prisma

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

I have a PostgreSQL database and my table contains a column for the id of the server and a column for the id of the user and some columns with the punishments that the user has in that user.

schema.prisma

```
model users {
  user_id                    BigInt
  guild_id                   BigInt
  bans                       Int
  kicks                      Int
  warns                      Int
}
```

How can I link the user_id and the guild_id together with the @unique and then fetch the user with the guild_id and the user_id in typescript?

```
    const query: any = await prisma.users.findMany({
        where: {
            user_id: BigInt("user_id"),
            guild_id: BigInt("guild_id")
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@@unique`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#unique-1) to have a combination of unique fields.

```
model users {
  user_id                    BigInt @id
  guild_id                   BigInt
  bans                       Int
  kicks                      Int
  warns                      Int

  @@unique([user_id, guild_id])
}
```

And then query it using `findUnique`.